# HTTP redirect in iframe instead of redirecting in the parent window

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, iframe, web-applications

I am working on a web application. 
In this web application I have to load a web page from a different servers(Eg: www.xyz.com) in an iframe. But sometimes when I try to load the web page from some different server in the iframe the server responds with HTTP status code 302 (stands for redirect) with the redirect link in the Location header field. When this happens the main window(my web app) is redirected instead of redirection happening only in the iframe. How can I ensure that the redirection happens only in the iframe instead of the main window?

Comment: This is not possible with server side only redirects. I bet that the website you are including inside an iframe has a special protection against this and when it detects that it simply uses javascript to bust out of the iframe and reload the parent. The best you could do is talk to the owners of the website you are trying to display inside an iframe.

Answer (score 10):

Use sandbox="..."

- allow-forms allows form submission
- allow-popups allows popups
- allow-pointer-lock allows pointer lock
- allow-same-origin allows the document to maintain its origin
- allow-scripts allows JavaScript execution, and also allows features to trigger automatically
- allow-top-navigation allows the document to break out of the frame by navigating the top-level window

**Top navigation is what you want to prevent, so leave that out and it will not be allowed.  Anything left out will be blocked**

ex.

```
        <iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="http://www.example.com"</iframe>
```

Comment: This does not navigate in the iframe but instead does an actual popup. Don't think that was the question.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is not about your redirection, but about what happens before: I suppose the user is submitting a form, through `POST`, and the webserver replies a 302 redirection as per best practice.

If a `<form>` has an `action` attribute pointing to another page, its answer will redirect the **top** iframe. I couldn't find any reference document stating that behavior, but that's how it works in current browsers.

The solution is to set the `target` attribute to `_self`:

```
<iframe>
    ...
    <form action="http..." target="_self" >
    ...
</iframe>
```

The `sandbox` attribute won't help here, you likely want to omit the attribute or to set `allow-forms allow-navigation` at least.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me when I set target="iframe_name".

Comment: This no longer works for different domains.